# MultiThreading in recusively functions in c++,edited..using OpenMP is slower than before

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I want to use MultiThreading for calculating multiply of 2 matrix recursively .Using [Strassen Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) .This algorithm needs 7 multiply in each step, and I want to create and use 7 threads for each step. Can I do this?

edit:
I want to work by openMP to do this.I use `#pragma omp parallel sections` for 7 multiply in each call function. But my program is slower than codes without `openMP`. my codes are below...(this alogorithm break each matrix to 4 matrix and by 7 multiply calculate multiply of 2 matrices.. for 8*8 matrices and adding matrices I use `SSE/AVX` method):

```
void AVXMult2(float *A,         //A input array             
              float *B,         //B input array
              float *C,         //Result array C
              int size          //size*size matrices
              )                        
{

if(size>8){                     //recurcively func, if size>8 must break matrix

    int s=size/2;               //s*s breaked matrices
    int s2=s*s;                 //s2 size of braked matrices
    int s3=size*s;              //s3 is offset of index of breaked matrices in A21,B21
    int s4=s3+s;                //s4 is offset of index of breaked matrices in A22,B22
    float *A11,*A12,*A21,*A22,*B11,*B12,*B21,*B22;//define breaked matrices

    //Allocate memory and allignement
    A11 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    A12 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    A21 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    A22 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    B11 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    B12 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    B21 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    B22 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);

    //Break A,B to 4 matrices

    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++){
            A11[i*s+j]=A[i*size+j];
            B11[i*s+j]=B[i*size+j];
            A12[i*s+j]=A[i*size+j+s];
            B12[i*s+j]=B[i*size+j+s];
            A21[i*s+j]=A[i*size+j+s3];
            B21[i*s+j]=B[i*size+j+s3];
            A22[i*s+j]=A[i*size+j+s4];
            B22[i*s+j]=B[i*size+j+s4];
                    }

    //temp arrays-------------
    float *tmp = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    float *tmp2 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);

    float* M1,*M2,*M3,*M4,*M5,*M6,*M7;
    //M1 to M8 are arrays based on Strassen algo.
    //M1----------------------
    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(7)
    {
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXadd(A11,A22,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(B11,B22,tmp2,s);
    M1 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(tmp,tmp2,M1,s);
    }
    //M2----------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXadd(A21,A22,tmp,s);
    M2 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(tmp,B11,M2,s);
    }
    //M3----------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXsub(B12,B22,tmp,s);
    M3 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(A11,tmp,M3,s);
    }
    //M4--------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXsub(B21,B11,tmp,s);
    M4 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(A22,tmp,M4,s);
    }

    //M5--------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXadd(A11,A12,tmp,s);
    M5 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(tmp,B22,M5,s);
    }
    //M6----------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXsub(A21,A11,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(B11,B12,tmp2,s);
    M6 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(tmp,tmp2,M6,s);
    }
    //M7----------------------
    #pragma omp section
    {AVXsub(A12,A22,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(B21,B22,tmp2,s);
    M7 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXMult2(tmp,tmp2,M7,s);
    }
    }
    //C11 to C22 are breakea matrices of result ------------------
    //C11--------------------
    float *C11 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXadd(M1,M4,tmp,s);
    AVXsub(tmp,M5,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(tmp,M7,C11,s);

    //C12-------------------
    float *C12 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXadd(M3,M5,C12,s);

    //C21--------------------
    float *C21 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXadd(M2,M4,C21,s);

    //C22---------------------
    float *C22 = (float*) _aligned_malloc(s2 * sizeof(float), 32);
    AVXsub(M1,M2,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(tmp,M3,tmp,s);
    AVXadd(tmp,M6,C22,s);


    //join C11 ... C44 to make 'C' result matrix 
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++){
            C[i*size+j]=C11[i*s+j];
            C[i*size+j+s]=C12[i*s+j];
            C[i*size+j+s3]=C21[i*s+j];
            C[i*size+j+s4]=C22[i*s+j];
                    }

    }

    //if size<=8 use avx88 function
        else
            avx88(A,B,C);

}
```

Comment: Yes you might be able to do that. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Oh by the way, remember that starting and ending a thread takes some overhead, and it's not good to have to many threads either (then the CPU will just spend time switching between the threads), so I would not recommend you to start seven threads in each recursive call, especially if you have more than a couple of levels of recursion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg . size of matrices are above 1000*1000 and there are many steps of recursive calls.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg . I want to use avx mechanism to multiply matrices. I have a code for multiply 8*8 matrices using SSE/AVX. I want to use this method recursively to brak matrices until 8*8 by strassen algorithm...

Comment: did any of the answers help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read about Strassen's algorithm on wikipedia?  It's unlikely to be helpful.  Instead you should use the standard O(n^3) algoithm.  To get the best efficiency you should use

1. Loop tiling
2. SIMD (SSE/AVX) (e.g. with intrinsics or with a SIMD library)
3. Loop unrolling to remove loop carried depenencies to increase instruction level parallism.
4. Threading (e.g. with OpenMP)

I would get the loop tiling working first.  That's going to give you your biggest performance boost.  Those cache misses really hurt.  I eventually got over 70% of the peak FLOPS (on a Sandy Bridge 4 core processor) which is better than Eigen but still not as good as the Intel MKL.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the operations at each step are independent and you are careful to gather all the results you should be able to use threads to parallelize the processing.

Comment: "paralyze" wins the "typo of the day" award with a wide margin. (And it's so often true, too!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. But I recommend another way: using extended instruction sets (SSE, SSE2, AVX, etc.) and automatic loop parallelization.

Recommended reading: [Auto-Parallelization and Auto-Vectorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx) in VS2012 - this will allow you to implement matrix multiplication in most efficient way almost without writing multithreaded stuff manually.

Comment: Coppersmith–Winograd_algorithm cannot be processed by modern hardware!!!because it only provides an advantage for matrices so large

Comment: Thanks, confused it with Strassen's. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is via the Thread Building Blocks library. It has a very simple mechanism that allows a task to split itself to sub tasks recursively.

It comes with sample code to a very similar problem.

Here's a [link](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/range_concept/blocked_range2d_cls.htm) to a parallel matrix multiply class using TBB.

TBB is free BTW.